# how to change background of element depending on position in browser

Tags: css, web, z-index

I have seen a couple of really fancy one-page websites in the past where certain elements would appear when scrolling through a page. From what I remember the effect seemed to be written using css only. I believe that should be possible with the z-index and position property?

Unfortunately, I can't find the pages again.

Anyone having a working example?

Cheers
Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is accomplished with `z-index` just like you said, but the other key is having the item beneath to have `position:fixed`, like so:

```
#blocker { position:relative; z-index:100; width:100%; height:100px; }
#uncover { position:fixed; right:0; top:0; z-index:50; }
```

Then when you scroll down the page, `#uncover` will be revealed as it will stay in the same relation to the browser window no matter where you scroll, but `#blocker` scrolls up with the page.  I've created a [fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/BaD26/1/).